# Outlook 2010 shows to big of a picture in a received email

Tags: html, css, joomla, outlook-2010

Im currently working on building a webshop for the company Im working for, and one of the things that Im currently working on, is order-mails that is being sent out to our customers when they have finished an order.

The webshop is being build on the CMS Joomla, and currently, we're still testing everything in  the webshop.

**Here's the problem:**
The order-mail I've made to this point, is made in HTML and CSS. In the top of the order-mail I've put in the company-logo. When my colleague (who's a test-customer at the moment) have placed an order, an email is sent to him and me. The mail my colleague receives looks fine, the logo resizes whenever he resizes the email-window. But the same mail that I receive, the logo in the top, is just totally out of proportion. The picture is the size as the original, even tho I defined it to be smaller in the HTML-/CSS-code.

- Does anyone know why that is ?
- Do I need to change anything in Outlook ?

Comment: is this a programming question? Um...

Comment: First test your HTML template on email clients http://putsmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS code? When it comes to HTML emails, you should not be using CSS for styling. To ensure they all cross email client compatible, you should be using tables.

So, firstly, remove the CSS you have for you image and use the following:

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:block; border:0;"  alt="" />
```

There **are** some email clients such as Apple Mail that will support CSS within the `<head` so you can use it, for example you may want to add a shadow to the image, however do not use it for structural styling, such as floating or positioning.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Adding "display:block;" to the image did seem to make the picture stay within proportion inside the mail. For a while.

I did also add a "max-width" inside a "div", that might have done something to the picture.